# Как сделать масштабируемую картинку в шапке сайта?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать динамичный масштаб картинки в шапке сайта? Честно сказать много чего перепробовал, но так и не добился нужного результата. Сайт на wordpress.
Пример моей проблемы:

Код HTML:

```
<div id="header" <img src="http://uvovng.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/images/gerb1.png" 
     width="150" height="160" style="position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 20px;>
```

Код CSS:

Если делаю в блоке

```
header, img {
  wight 10%; 
}
```

так меняется масштаб картинки, но этот размер он применяет ко всем картинкам `img`, не только в `header`. Как мне применить этот атрибут только для картинок которые расположены в шапке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ещё у самой картинки сделать `id`, и по нему уже задавать селектор

```
<img id="header-img" src="...">

#header-img {
  width:10%;
}
```

или через класс

```
<img class="header-img" src="...">

.header-img {
  width:10%;
}
```

Comment: Ваш приём тоже попробовал, работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

Добрый день!
Назначьте блоку, который оборачивает картинку, какой-то класс и оттолкнитесь от него в селекторе CSS, сделав его тем самым более специфичным.

```
<div id="header" class="header">
   <img src="http://uvovng.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/images/gerb1.png" width="150" height="160"/>
</div>

<style>
    .header img {
        width: 10%;
    }
<style>
```

https://codepen.io/Nick_Gromov/pen/gemBqz

Comment: Да, спасибо, так гораздо лучше) Всё работает.